# How safe is pandas apply() function with respect to Python requests()?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am implementing a web scraping algorithm in Python. I have a dataframe in which one column contains URLs. For each row, using these URLs, I use python requests() to open the URL, find a particular entry and return it, to create a new column called 'Value'.

For this, I defined my custom function `getvalue(row)` that takes the argument as the row, does the above function and returns the value. I use pandas `apply()` function for this, and it appears to be much faster than looping each row of the dataframe.

How safe is it to use `apply()`. Will the `requests()` and the returned values be messed up, and will the returned values be mismatched with a different row?

Comment: No, why would it be "messed up" or mismatched? apply may call the function a couple times on the first row.... Why don't you just *try it*.

Comment: I did try it. But it doesnt seem feasible to manually verify the value for every row. So I was wondering if I can assume that it would give the right result.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work the way it's documented to work? What exactly are you even asking? `apply` is just a for loop anyway

Comment: Oh. I thought ```apply()``` parallelizes the computation. I see now that it is a for loop, I'll read up on it a little more on its working. Thanks!

Comment: No, it absolutely does not parallelize anything, unless they changed something in some recent version. But they wouldn't just break backwards compatibility because it's always been documented to work on each row... The whole **point** of pandas is to maintain and be aware of index alignment